# Hiding API key info from public facing github for Twitter bot running on Heroku?

Tags: github, heroku, bots, api-key

I've been teaching myself node.js using some tutorials online. I successfully made a Twitter bot and deployed it using Heroku and everything works great.

However, my Twitter API keys are contained in a config.js file that is freely available on the github repository that my Heroku app is linked to.  I've since removed this sensitive data from github.

I have searched for answers on this and have found a lot of conflicting and confusing solutions and was hoping somebody could direct me to an easy-to-follow solution.  If my API keys are not available on the git, where do I store them and how do I instruct my app to retrieve them?

This is the main app.js file, note I've combined a couple of different tutorials and so what it does is provide a "Hello World" output on screen and also Tweets "Hello, learning node.js!" on my chosen Twitter account:

```
const http = require('http');
const port=process.env.PORT || 3000
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.end('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
});
server.listen(port,() => {
console.log(`Server running at port `+port);
});

var Twit = require('twit')

var fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path'),
Twit = require('twit'),
config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.js'));

var T = new Twit(config);

T.post('statuses/update', { status: 'Hello, learning node.js!' }, 
function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

The config.js file referenced above looks like:

```
var config = {
  consumer_key:         'xxx',
  consumer_secret:      'xxx',
  access_token:         'xxx',
  access_token_secret:  'xxx'
}

module.exports = config;
```

This all works with the correct keys in the config.js file, but obviously this is not ideal security-wise!

I'm a bit of a novice here as you can tell, but keen to learn what the correct approach would be to resolve this.  Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku let you set some environment variables, more details [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), and you can get them with `process.env.MY_ENV_VAR`.
This is a recommended way for building applications referring to the [Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about heroku but I guess you can set environment variables.

And to have access to these variable in your dev machine, you can set them in a .env file or directly in your computer environment variable. If you want to use a `.env` file, then I guess you'll need the [npm dotenv module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) (and obviously add `.env` to your `.gitignore`).

For your exemple you could have the following `.env` file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
consumer_key=       'xxx',
consumer_secret=    'xxx',
access_token=       'xxx',
access_token_secret='xxx'
```

Then you can use them with `process.env.VAR_NAME` so if you want the consumer key you can do `process.env.consumer_key`. Usually these variables are named uppercase tho.

It's also commonly used to set a `NODE_ENV` variable which allow you to determine if you are running in `development`, `production`, `test` ... mode

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this.  I added the environment variables on Heroku (via desktop, not using CLI), and then changed my config.js file to:

```
var config = {
  consumer_key:         process.env.consumer_key,
  consumer_secret:      process.env.consumer_secret,
  access_token:         process.env.access_token,
  access_token_secret:  process.env.access_token_secret
}

module.exports = config;
```